# How do I find the first nonblank cell in a column?

Tags: excel, vba

The first row is all headers, and the first column are all dates.  I am looking for vba code/macro to find and select the first non empty cell in each column after the headers.  For example find the first nonempty cell in the range B2 and select it.

Comment: This is not a "Give me teh codez" site, but a site dedicated to helping programmers.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Note: Their is a difference between blank and empty.

For First Non-Blank (as in question title) Try:

```
With Columns("B")
    .Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues).Activate
End With
```

For First Non-Empty (as in question body) Try:

Unlike above this will also find non-empty cells where a formula equates to blank ie =IF(A1=1,A1,"")

```
With Columns("B")
    .Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas).Activate
End With
```

Comment: Whoops, Im such a turkey, apologies Ari and thanks Tim, I misread the question.  Please see my edit for a solution.

Comment: +1 for clever way of finding non-blank cells, even though I would guess the OP meant non-empty (but who knows) and for this I prefer `.End(xlDown)`.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I'm looking for non-blanks. I am also pretty new to VBA, how would I put your first edit code for non-Blank above into a sub? The way I put it in isn't working. I had sub firstval() then your code then end sub..am i missing something before the with?

Comment: No thats all the code.  Your going to have to be more descriptive than "its not working".  Did you get an error message, did the code compile, did it not select the correct cell or what did it do wrong etc..  My understanding is that you want to select the first non blank cell in column b.  So starting at B1 the code will look below B1 to the first non-blank cell say eg B20 (the first cell that has a value) and select that cell.

Answer (score 3):

In each column `i`, the first non empty cell is

```
set first_ne = cells(2,i)

if isempty(first_ne.value) then
  set first_ne = first_ne.end(xldown)
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `IsEmpty` function can check if a cell is blank or not:

```
Sub GetFirstNonEmptyCell()
    Dim startCell as range, firstNonEmptyCell as range

    Set startCell = Range("B2") 'change this depending on which column you are looking at

    If VBA.IsEmpty(startCell.Value) Then
        MsgBox "No data in this column"
    Else
        Set firstNonEmptyCell = startCell.End(xlDown)
        MsgBox "First non empty cell is " & firstNonEmptyCell.Address
    End If    
End Sub
```

Comment: Doesn't behave properly if B2 is empty. `MsgBox "No data in this column"` should be replaced by `MsgBox "First non empty cell is " & startCell.Address`.

Comment: @Jean-Francois Corbett - can you explain more? From OP, I read it that row 1 is the header row so if row 2 is empty there would be no data in the column. So if B2 is empty then there isn't a non-empty cell (other than the header row in row 1)???

Comment: @Remnant: The OP wants to "select the first non empty cell in each column after the headers." I don't see anything about "if row 2 is empty there would be no data in the column." Maybe there is data further down. That's the whole point of the OP's question, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Jean-Francois Corbett - Ok. See your point. Let's see if OP comes back with any comments. With the answers provided he should be able to make some progress at the least

Comment: Hi there, sorry for the late response.  I'll try to clarify how my worksheet looks.  Cell A1 says Date, and A2 downward for a few thousand rows are dates.  Cells B1, C1, D1..etc. are the variable names.  Most of my data starts closer to the end of the data. Every search I've done looks for 'last cell with data', or 'first empty cell'.  I think I can figure out the rest of what I'm doing if I can just find the first cell in column B that has a value in it other than the variable name.  I'd like to find it and select it.  Like if the first data point is 20 on 12/03/2005.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @Ari - I think I understand now and think that you should be able to use the code posted by me and others to get what you need...